# Cardlayout doesn't appear panels inside cards on InternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout

I have a cardLayout used upon an InternalFrame

```
public class CardWindow extends InternalWindowTemplate{
    CardLayout cardLayout;
    private final JLabel label1, label2;
    private final JPanel panel1, panel2, cards, card1, card2;

    public CardWindow(){
        super("Elements", false, true, false, false,438,520);
        this.panel1= new JPanel(); 
        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);

        this.panel2= new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        this.label1= new JLabel("Label #1");
        panel1.add(label1);

        this.label2= new JLabel("Label #2");
        panel2.add(label2);

//        create first card
        this.card1 = new JPanel(); 
        card1.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        card1.add(panel1);
        card1.add(panel2);

    //        create second card
        this.card2 = new JPanel();
        card2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        label1.setText("1");
        label2.setText("2");
        card2.add(panel1);
        card2.add(panel2);

        this.cards = new JPanel();
        this.cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        cards.setLayout(cardLayout);
        cards.add(card1);
        cards.add(card2);

        addComponentToInternalWindow(cards);
}
```

The last statement is from my internal window abstract class

```
public abstract class InternalWindowTemplate{
//...
    public void addComponentToInternalWindow(Component component){
        setFlowLayout();
        getContainer().add(component);
    }
}
```

When I run it, I can see only the orange background from card1, but not the panels I added. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "When I run it, I can see only the orange background from card1, but not the panels I added. Why is that?"

A component can have one and *only* one parent. If a component is added to more than one container, only the last container it was added to will maintain the component.

That being said, you add `panel1` and `panel2` to `card1`. Then you add the same `panel1` and `panel2` to `card2`. So `card2` is the winner. Since `card1` is the first to be shown (as it was the first to be added), you will only see an empty `card1` with the orange background